# Shredding XML in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2017

Given the following SQL:

```sql
drop table if exists #testXML

create table #testXML (InputXML xml)

insert into #testXML
values ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<document>
<table name="tableName1">
<column name="ID">000010313500011171011710001 </column>
<column name="StartDate">10/27/2019</column>
<column name="EndDate">11/02/2019</column>
</table>
</document>')
```

I'm trying to get output like this:

```
ID                                 StartDate     EndDate
000010313500011171011710001        10/27/2019    11/02/2019
```

Here's my start, but I'm just flailing at this point.

```sql
SELECT  
       px1.tbl.value('@name','nvarchar(50)') as TableName
      ,px2.col.value('@name','nvarchar(50)') as ColName
from #testXML px
cross apply   inputxml.nodes ('/document/table') as px1(tbl)
cross apply   inputxml.nodes ('/document/table/column') as px2(col)
```

This is on SQL Server 2017.

Comment: You can't get dynamic column names without dynamic Sql. you would need to take your current results and use a dynamic pivot technique (plenty of answers on this site) on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL needs to be adjusted as follows, by leveraging the `@name` attribute value.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (InputXML xml)

INSERT INTO @tbl (InputXML)
VALUES ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<document>
    <table name="tableName1">
        <column name="ID">000010313500011171011710001</column>
        <column name="StartDate">10/27/2019</column>
        <column name="EndDate">11/02/2019</column>
    </table>
</document>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT col.value('(column[@name="ID"]/text())[1]','nvarchar(50)') as ID
    , col.value('(column[@name="StartDate"]/text())[1]','DATE') as StartDate
    , col.value('(column[@name="EndDate"]/text())[1]','DATE') as EndDate
FROM @tbl tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.InputXML.nodes('/document/table') AS tab(col);
```

> Output

```
+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
|             ID              | StartDate  |  EndDate   |
+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
| 000010313500011171011710001 | 2019-10-27 | 2019-11-02 |
+-----------------------------+------------+------------+
```